# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'splits'

Tags: python, attributeerror

```
mnist_train = mnist_dataset['train']
mnist_test = mnist_dataset['test']
num_validation_sample =0.1* mnist_info.splits['train'].num_example
num_validation_sample =tf.cast(num_validation_samples, tf.init64)

num_test_samples = mnist_info.splits['test'].num_example
num_test_samples =tf.cast(num_test_samples, tf.init64)

def scale (image, label):
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    image /=255.
    return image, label

scaled_train_and_validation_data = mnist_train.map(scale)

test_data = mnist_test.map(scale)

BUFFER_SIZE = 10000

shuffled_train_and_validation_data = scaled_train_and_validation_data(BUFFER_SIZE)
validation_data = shuffled_train_and_validation_data.take(num_validation_sample)
train_data = shuffled_train_and_validation_data.skip(num_validation_sample)

BATCH_SIZE = 100
train_data = train_data.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
validation_data = validation_data.batch(num_validation_sample)
#test_data

validation_inputs, validation_targets = next(iter(validation_data))
```

> I got the following error when I run the code:

> Traceback (most recent call last)  in
> ()

> ----> 3 num_validation_sample =0.1* mnist_info.splits['train'].num_example

> **AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'splits'**

Answer (score 0):

The error means that `mnist_info` is a `dict` and dicts do not have a split method, so there is a logic error in your code. You probably are looking for replacing it with:
`mnist_info.get('train').num_example`, but you should provide an example of what is `mnist_info` and what you want to do, so we can be sure what's wrong with the code.